# Compute the output of 97 after a byte substitution in AES?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I understand the framework of the calculation, however I am struggling to determine the inverse of 97 in GF(256). Any straight forward explanation would be greatly appreciated. My resources have not been very helpful in this calculation. My textbook uses reduction to show this, but I've never used such a technique before and find it confusing. Certainly not the best course to take online.

From tables, I know that the answer is 72, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E = \operatorname{GF}(256)$ is constructed via the irreducible polynomial
$$
f = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 \in \mathbf{F}_{2}[x].
$$
Now the hex $97$ represents the polynomial $g$ (element of $E$) whose binary coefficients are
$$
1001\ 0111,
$$
so
$$
g = x^7 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1.
$$
Use Euclid's algorithm to find that the inverse of $g$ modulo $f$ is
$$
h = x^6+x^5+x^4+x,
$$
whose coefficients are
$$
0111\ 0010
$$
which would give me hex $72$.

[Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity) finds polynomials $h, t$ such that
$$
1 = h g + t f,
$$
so that $1 \equiv h g \pmod{f}$, and $h$ is the required inverse.

Comment: You are correct. I found a table that shows 72 to be the inverse. Would you mind please showing how you got h? I am not getting that as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @user42864, I have added an explanation in my answer, with a link to Wikipedia. Please let me know if this is OK.

Comment: You apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm? I've never applied that to polynomials before. With numbers, I completely understand how to perform EEA. I have no idea with polynomials. Can I think of this as 97e is congruent to 1 (mod 283) and apply the EEA to find e?

Comment: @user42864, look at a document on Rijndael/AES. The idea is, go as I did from hex $97$ to binary $1001\ 0111$ to the polynomial $x^7 + 0 x^6 + 0 x^5 + x^4 + 0 x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$, and then invert this one modulo $f$ using the (Extended) Euclidean Algorithm. This is no different for polynomials than it is for integers, just use polynomial division as you learned it in school. It won't work with numbers as you are trying to do.

Comment: @user42864, see for instance the following document, it's all there http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf

Comment: So I am trying to find {x^7+ x^4 + x^2 + x +1} mod {x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1}. Shouldn't I be able to apply the division algorithm for polynomials? I get r(x) = {-x^5 + x^4 - x^2 + 1}.

Comment: So when I apply EEA with I begin to get coefficients at the fifth recursion of x: -x^5  - 2x^4 - 2x^3 - x^2 -x +1. Is this correct or is there an error in my math? How do you handle coefficients?

Comment: @user42864, sorry, no time now, will get back later. Coefficients are in the field with two elements, though, so you only get $0$ or $1$, depending whether the number you get is even or odd.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for your time and patience with me. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @user42864, you're welcome!